# Hyper-V on Windows 8.1: Not able to share VHDX between VM and host

Tags: hyper-v

I would like to share the VHDX file attached to my VM (Win8.1 as well) with the host System. Therefor I have enabled the advanced Feature within the VM under SCSI controller "activate sharing of virtual harddisk" (literally translated from German).

Unfortunately when I click on Apply I receive:

```
Fehler beim Übernehmen von Festplatten Änderungen

Fehler beim Ändern des Geräts "Virtual Hard Disk".

Der Speicher, in dem sich die virtuelle Festplatte befindet, unterstützt die Freigabe virtueller Festplatten nicht.
```

Which means something like: The storage that contains the vhdx file does not Support sharing. Then what criteria does my storage has to fullfil? The vhdx files are stored on my SSD NTFS and Basic...

Comment: What leads you to believe this would be supported on Windows 8.1?  The [docs only mention 2012R2/2012 support](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn281956.aspx).  You understand that this is for **failover clusters** right.  Only one system can be actively using the shared resource at once.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to mimic virtualbox shared folder feature. I know there is enhanced session mode which allows me to map drive. my vm's are in a seperate vlan so i cant and wont easily share a folder to exchange files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn281956.aspx) that Zoredache links to in the comments also specify that it this feature is also only meant to share virtual disks between virtual machines - not between the virtual machine and the host.

But to directly answer your question, there are some hard requirements to support this feature:

- Virtual disks are meant to be shared between other virtual machines - not between the virtual machine and the host.
- The guest OS needs to be 2012/2012R2
- The virtual disks must reside on either shared CSV volume or on a shared SMB3 fileserver accessible by both hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing a virtual disk isn't the same thing as sharing a file system.  You're looking for a shared file system.  If you want that, enable a file share on one machine or the other and then use the files through networking.

If you do share a virtual disk between two VMs (which can, as the others have noted, only happen when the VHDX is stored on a clustered file system) you need to then use clustering within the group of VMs to arbitrate access to the disk, so that the various VMs don't clobber each others' block writes to the disk and corrupt the file system on the virtual disk.  This pretty much requires clustering software running within the set of guest VMs, which is the reason that this feature doesn't work at all for Windows 8.1, even within a VM.

It is actually possible for more than one VM to be writing to the shared VHDX simultaneously.  You can enable the CSV file system within the guest cluster and it will allow multiple cluster nodes to write at the same time, as long as the writing is happening to files that already exist on disk and to regions of the files that already exist.  This makes sense for workloads like SQL Server using a file server as backend storage.  For other workloads, it makes more sense to avoid CSV and let one VM use the disk at a time.  A Windows file server cluster will still be highly available, by the way, in that one VM can die without interrupting file service.  The ownership of the disk will seamlessly shift to another member of the file server cluster.

This, by the way, points to the reason why the shared VHDX needs to be on CSV at the hosting layer.  The entire feature makes no sense unless the shared VHDX is on storage that has no single point of failure.